# INFINITY problem while dividing is iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, infinity

I am getting infinity problem in an iPhon application. The problem is very strange. I need to calculate the zoom limit using the following formula.

```
zoomLimit = 1/(mapState.iBufferMult*0.75);
```

The value of mapState.iBufferMult = 3

The problem is that most of the type the formula gives the correct value 0.44. But sometimes it gives INFINITY.

Can anyone tell me why it is doing like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why it is doing like that.

Yes, I can: when `mapState.iBufferMult` is `0` (zero) then:

```
zoomLimit = 1/(mapState.iBufferMult*0.75)
          = 1/(0*0.75)
          = 1/0
          = INFINITY
```

Solve the `mapState.iBufferMult` problem and you've solved this one.

Answer (score 1):

Because `mapState.iBufferMult` is 0 in the cases where the expression is INFINITY.  Something in your program is setting it to 0.  Log it and the result of the division and check every time.

Answer (score 1):

because sometimes `mapState.iBufferMult` == `0`.

Check you haven't got a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because *some* of the time, `mapState` is nil or `mapState.iBufferMult` is 0.

Or the problem lies outside of this line.

Maybe set a breakpoint there and halt when zoomLimit is INFINITY.